# Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates for Bb

Tags: r

I am trying to fit an equation through the given data but have been unsuccessful

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(2.27, 2.72, 3.18, 3.63, 4.08, 4.54, 4.99, 5.45, 5.90, 6.35, 6.81, 7.26, 7.71, 8.17, 8.62, 9.08, 9.53, 9.98, 10.44, 10.89, 11.34, 11.80, 12.25, 12.71, 13.16, 13.61, 14.07, 14.52, 14.97, 15.43, 15.88, 16.34, 16.79, 17.24, 17.70, 18.15, 18.61, 19.06, 19.51, 19.97, 20.42, 20.87, 21.33),
              y=c(200.723, 249.508, 293.024, 327.770, 354.081, 372.079, 381.493, 383.478, 378.901, 368.833, 354.063, 336.278, 316.076, 293.924, 271.432, 248.239, 225.940, 204.327, 183.262, 163.830, 145.750, 128.835, 113.568, 99.451, 87.036, 75.876, 65.766, 57.008, 49.223, 42.267, 36.352, 31.062, 26.580, 22.644, 19.255, 16.391, 13.811, 11.716, 9.921, 8.364, 7.087, 5.801, 4.523))
frequency <- (data$x)
brightness <- (data$y)*2.71057477e-3

# Define the Planck blackbody equation as a function in R
B <- function(frequency, t) {
 h <- 6.62607015e-34
c <- 299792458
k <- 1.380649e-23
(2 * h * frequency^3 * c^-2) / (exp((h * frequency) / (k * t)) - 1)
}

 library(stats)
fit <- nls(brightness ~ B(frequency, t), data = data, start = list(t = 2.5)) 

# Summarize the fit
summary(fit)

# Plot the data and the fitted model
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = frequency, y = brightness)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line(aes(x = frequency, y = predict(fit)))
```

I just need a basic scatter plot of the data with the equation fitted over it as a line

Comment: Use `expm1(...)` instead of `exp(...) - 1`. I get a successful (but not actually good) fit then. I'm not sure your model is suitable. (Also, put `frequency` and `brightness` into the data.frame.)

Comment: @Roland I still get the same error, I did use expm1, unsure about how to put frequency and brightness into the data.frame                                                              B <- function(frequency, t) {
  h <- 6.62607015e-34
  c <- 299792458
  k <- 1.380649e-23
  (2 * h * frequency^3 * c^-2) / (expm1((h * frequency) / (k * t)))
}


library(stats)
fit <- nls(brightness ~ B(frequency, t), data = data, start = list(t = 2.5))

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(2.27, 2.72, 3.18, 3.63, 4.08, 4.54, 4.99, 5.45, 5.90, 6.35, 6.81, 7.26, 7.71, 8.17, 8.62, 9.08, 9.53, 9.98, 10.44, 10.89, 11.34, 11.80, 12.25, 12.71, 13.16, 13.61, 14.07, 14.52, 14.97, 15.43, 15.88, 16.34, 16.79, 17.24, 17.70, 18.15, 18.61, 19.06, 19.51, 19.97, 20.42, 20.87, 21.33),
                   y=c(200.723, 249.508, 293.024, 327.770, 354.081, 372.079, 381.493, 383.478, 378.901, 368.833, 354.063, 336.278, 316.076, 293.924, 271.432, 248.239, 225.940, 204.327, 183.262, 163.830, 145.750, 128.835, 113.568, 99.451, 87.036, 75.876, 65.766, 57.008, 49.223, 42.267, 36.352, 31.062, 26.580, 22.644, 19.255, 16.391, 13.811, 11.716, 9.921, 8.364, 7.087, 5.801, 4.523))
data$frequency <- (data$x)
data$brightness <- (data$y)*2.71057477e-3

# Define the Planck blackbody equation as a function in R
B <- function(frequency, t) {
  h <- 6.62607015e-34
  c <- 299792458
  k <- 1.380649e-23
  (2 * h * frequency^3 * c^-2) / (expm1((h * frequency) / (k * t)))
}

library(stats)
fit <- nls(brightness ~ B(frequency, t), data = data, start = list(t = 2.5)) 

# Summarize the fit
summary(fit)

# Plot the data and the fitted model
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = frequency, y = brightness)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x = frequency, y = predict(fit)))
```

[image: resulting plot showing the data and predictions]

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked as comments on your previous questions, **What are the units on frequency and brightness?**
Going back to your original question the units on data$x is 1/cm so it is not frequency but wavenumber and brightness is MJy/sr which is equal to 1.256E-19 kg/s2

So if you use the correct form of the Plank's equation (There is a typo on the Wikipedia page) and perform the unit conversions you are able to perform a fit. Not necessary a great fit.

```
 data <- data.frame(freq = c(2.27, 2.72, 3.18, 3.63, 4.08, 4.54, 4.99, 5.45, 5.90, 6.35, 6.81, 7.26, 7.71, 8.17, 8.62, 9.08, 9.53, 9.98, 10.44, 10.89, 11.34, 11.80, 12.25, 12.71, 13.16, 13.61, 14.07, 14.52, 14.97, 15.43, 15.88, 16.34, 16.79, 17.24, 17.70, 18.15, 18.61, 19.06, 19.51, 19.97, 20.42, 20.87, 21.33), 
                   brightness = c(200.723, 249.508, 293.024, 327.770, 354.081, 372.079, 381.493, 383.478, 378.901, 368.833, 354.063, 336.278, 316.076, 293.924, 271.432, 248.239, 225.940, 204.327, 183.262, 163.830, 145.750, 128.835, 113.568, 99.451, 87.036, 75.876, 65.766, 57.008, 49.223, 42.267, 36.352, 31.062, 26.580, 22.644, 19.255, 16.391, 13.811, 11.716, 9.921, 8.364, 7.087, 5.801, 4.523))

planck <- function(freq, t, h, c, k) {
   # freq = wavenumber * c
   #  (2 * h * freq^3) / (c^2) * 1/(exp((h * freq) / (k * t)) - 1) 
   (2 * h * c * freq^3) * 1/(exp((h*c*freq)/(k*t))-1) 
}

# fit the data using nls
h = 6.62607e-34
c= 3e8
k = 1.38065e-23
data$freq<- data$freq*100 #(convert from 1/cm to 1/m)
fit <- nls(brightness*1.256E-19 ~ planck(freq, t, h, c, k), start = list(t = 3), data = data)
summary(fit)
#1.256E-19 to convert from kg/s^2 to MJy/sr
brightness_fit <- predict(fit, data)/1.256E-19

# plot the data and the fitted curve
plot(data$freq, data$brightness, xlab = "Frequency (1/m)", ylab = "Brightness")
lines(data$freq, y=brightness_fit, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to answer your question, y is in MJy/sr and x is in 1/cm